# getting pc information for supported ram clock

Tags: memory

Could anybody tell me how to know how much RAM my pc supports, for example the max memory (1GB currently installed) and the max clock speed (667MHz currently installed with DDR2), so when upgrading to 2GB I can decide whether I'm able to buy some 800MHz DDR2 RAM for better performance.

And what is better for performance and speed, to have 2 x 1GB or 1 x 2GB RAM?

I have a DELL Vostro 200 desktop pc

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E4500 @ 2.20GHz

RAM 2 x 512MB DDR2 667MHz

Graphics Intel(R) G33/G31 Express Chipset Family

Windows 7 Ultimate x86 and managing to install the x64 when upgrading my hardware.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kingston.com reports it should handle 1 gig sticks...it lets you specify by model and shop compatible products: http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/modelsinfo.asp?SysID=38969&mfr=Dell&model=Vostro+200+Mini+Tower+%2F+Slim+Tower&search_type=&root=us&LinkBack=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kingston.com&Sys=38969-Dell-Vostro+200+Mini+Tower+%2F+Slim+Tower&distributor=0&submit1=Search